# Table Full how to Use New some help here

Tags: android, class

I have a game and a class with Questions and answsers.
so after a lot of levels (actually 335) my class was full 65536 characters,

1. so I need to use new class?
2. I use the "QuestionLibrary" a lot of times in my game how to replace it if level is > 335 with the new class name QuestionLibrary2?

This is my class:

```
private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();
```

I use mquestionlibrary like this:

```
question1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
question2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
question3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
question4.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice4(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
question5.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice5(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1));
```

Comment: Reaching such a high character count in a single class shows bad design, this needs refactoring, however what stops you from creating this second class `QuestionLibrary2` and if the level count is > 335 instantiate the new class? It is just a `if...then...else` statement

Comment: my game take the questions and anwsers from tables from other class "QuestionLibrary".
so i create a "QuestionLibrary2"
and i wanna use it to my game.. what code need to use to replace all the Questionlibrary to QuestionLibrary2 if level >335?

Comment: Share your code (not the huge `QuestionLibrary` class) but the rest of your code that uses this class

Comment: i use mquestionlibrary like this:

 question1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber + level - 1));
            question2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber + level - 1));
            question3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber + level - 1));
            question4.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice4(mQuestionNumber + level - 1));
            question5.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice5(mQuestionNumber + level - 1));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs redesign and refactoring, I believe you are doing a lot of repetitive work that can be replaced. **Strictly** addressing to your specific question on how to use `QuestionLibrary` and `QuestionLibrary2`:

```
private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary1 = new QuestionLibrary();
private QuestionLibrary2 mQuestionLibrary2 = new QuestionLibrary2();
// blah blah

if(level<335) {
    question1.setText(mQuestionLibrary1.getChoice1(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
    question2.setText(mQuestionLibrary1.getChoice2(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
    question3.setText(mQuestionLibrary1.getChoice3(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
    question4.setText(mQuestionLibrary1.getChoice4(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
    question5.setText(mQuestionLibrary1.getChoice5(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1));
} else {
    question1.setText(mQuestionLibrary2.getChoice1(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
    question2.setText(mQuestionLibrary2.getChoice2(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
    question3.setText(mQuestionLibrary2.getChoice3(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
    question4.setText(mQuestionLibrary2.getChoice4(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
    question5.setText(mQuestionLibrary2.getChoice5(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1));
}
```

**UPDATE**
Create a method which takes `level` as parameter and returns either `QuestionLibrary` or `QuestionLibrary2` as results. To achieve this you have both classes to share a common `interface`.

E.g.

```
public interface QuestionLibraryInterface {
    String getChoice1(int number);
    String getChoice2(int number);
    String getChoice3(int number);
    String getChoice4(int number);
    String getChoice5(int number);
}
```

Then declare that your `QuestionLibrary` classes implement this interface:

```
public class QuestionLibrary implements QuestionLibraryInterface {
     //override interface methods with your class's code here
}

public class QuestionLibrary2 implements QuestionLibraryInterface {
     //override interface methods with your class's code here
}
```

Lastly create the method mentioned in the beginning:

```
public QuestionLibraryInterface chooseQuestionLibraryByLevel(int level) {
    if(level<335) {
        return mQuestionLibrary1;
    } else {
        return mQuestionLibrary2;
    }
}
```

And in your code replace the

```
mQuestionLibrary1.getChoice1(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)
```

part with

```
chooseQuestionLibraryByLevel(level).getChoice1(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)
```

So this will become:

```
question1.setText(chooseQuestionLibraryByLevel(level).getChoice1(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
question2.setText(chooseQuestionLibraryByLevel(level).getChoice2(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
question3.setText(chooseQuestionLibraryByLevel(level).getChoice3(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
question4.setText(chooseQuestionLibraryByLevel(level).getChoice4(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1)); 
question5.setText(chooseQuestionLibraryByLevel(level).getChoice5(mQuestionNumbe‌​r + level - 1));
```

Comment: is there any more easy to way to change only mQuestionLibrary1 to mQuestionLibrary2?    i use mQuestionLibrary1 177 times in my code so i need some more specific to chooce the classes if the level is >355 or level <355.. something like with the same name but with one if in the top to look the level and chooce the class..

Comment: Check my updated answer, I strongly advise you to redesign/review/rework/refactor your code. Using 177 times `mQuestionLibrary1` is not good thing to do.